# Unicode Decode Error while geocoding MMqgis

Tags: qgis, geocoding, python-2.7, mmqgis

Running Qgis, trying to geocode a CSV file using MMQGIS

Qgis gets to the 66th element (there are 119) and returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BPolinsky.MDC/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 1198, in run
    shapefilename, notfoundfile, fields, service, 1)
  File "C:/Users/BPolinsky.MDC/.qgis2/python/plugins\mmqgis\mmqgis_library.py", line 1901, in mmqgis_geocode_web_service
    attributes.append(unicode(row[z], 'utf-8').strip())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

the question is, is the error something that I can change by either using a different plugin, playing around the the content / map settings, or would I need to go into the python of Qgis? If so, how would I go into its python? Why am I getting this error?

The other questions I've seen had to do with python mostly, not python filtered through qgis.

Comment: There could be some funky character or combination of characters in the attributes of that element. Look for non alpha numeric data in the 66th element.

Comment: thanks! turned out the problem was an E with a mark over it, as in café